# mod_rewrite, I want to detect if a file exists in another directory and retrieve that

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to point to a sub directory file if it exists.

Currently I have in an .htaccess file at the webroot:

```
RewriteCond my_sub_dir/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ my_sub_dir/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]
```

Basically I want http://example.com/js/application.js to point to my_sub_dir/js/application.js if it exists

Answer (score 0):

`-d` tests if the given path is a valid path to an existing directory. If you want to test for regular files, use `-f` instead. But you also need to provide an absolute filesystem path. So try this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my_sub_dir%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my_sub_dir%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: changed it up, it didn't fix it.
 I had the -f anyways (mis-typing). I don't seem to get an absolute system path for this though. I get an absolute path from the VirtualDirectory DocumentRoot.