# mod_rewrite: If the file exists in another directory, serve that one instead

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website at `example.com/test/`. Lets say the website is laid out as such:

```
example.com
└── test/
    ├── assets/
    │   └─ stylesheet.css
    │
    ├── .htaccess
    └── index.php
```

`index.php` here is the router, as is apparently cool to do nowadays.

Whenever the user requests a page like `example.com/test/stylesheet.css`, I want to check to see if `assets/` has that file, and if so, serve that file instead of giving the URL to `index.php`. Ideally, the following would work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond assets/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ assets/$1
```

But since `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is an absolute path, `assets/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` turns out to be something like `assets/home/public/test/stylesheet.css`. `%{REQUEST_URI}` is no better: it turns into `assets/test/stylesheet.css`. I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320910/mod-rewrite-i-want-to-detect-if-a-file-exists-in-another-directory-and-retrieve), but the answer didn't work either.

Is there any way, without resorting to PHP, to do this? (If not, I'll just use PHP's `readfile`, but I don't want to worry about LFI or anything.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `the %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` and `%{REQUEST_URI}` vars

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ assets/$1
```

---

EDIT: I see, try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(.+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/assets/%2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/assets/%2 [L,R]
```

Comment: I've tried that: the problem is that `%{REQUEST_URI}` is `test/stylesheet.css`. The actual rewrite becomes `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets/test/stylesheet.css`, where I need `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test/assets/stylesheet.css`

Comment: @arxanas wait, so there's an `assets` folder in any path? What if someone requests `/a/b/c/d/e/f/foo.css`, does that go to `/a/assets/b/c/d/e/f/foo.css` or `/a/b/c/d/e/f/assets/foo.css`?

Comment: The .htaccess is in the `test/` directory, so it doesn't have to match *any* first directory. But the expected behavior would be `/a/assets/b/c/d/e/f/foo.css`.

Comment: @arxanas Ah I see, see the edit, you can use `%` backreferences to match against the URI

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! But would this be vulnerable to a path-traversal attack? I should think not, but I would hate to be proven wrong in production.

Comment: @arxanas I think the only thing you may need to worry about is if there are directories in `/assets/` and you don't end with a trailing slash so apache redirects you, exposing the internal rewrite. But that shouldn't happen because `-f` only applies to files.

Comment: I used the first part of your answer. `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets/%{REQUEST_URI} -f` is wrong. REQUEST_URI starts with a slash, so it should be: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets%{REQUEST_URI} -f`

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that a subfolder of ```/assets/example/index.html``` works when the url is ```/example/```?

Answer (score 0):

I had a Wordpress site and tried to serve resources from four alternative directories using this file `wp-content/uploads/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ([^/]+$)
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/$1 -f
    RewriteRule ([^/]+$) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/$1 [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ([^/]+$)
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/$1 -f
    RewriteRule ([^/]+$) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/$1 [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ([^/]+$)
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/$1 -f
    RewriteRule ([^/]+$) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/$1 [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ([^/]+$)
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/$1 -f
    RewriteRule ([^/]+$) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/$1 [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

And it worked.